# Considerations when handing over botched DIY alternator/electrical repair to a mechanic

Tags: alternator, diy

I tried following an in depth guide my my exact car for replacing an alternator. I intended to first replace alternator brushes, and then replace the alternator if brushes were not sufficient. After resolving some major difficulties, two very scratched hands over a few hours, I couldn't manage to fully release the alternator due to a very stubborn clip on the rear of the alternator. I just can't get a solid grip on it. The clip holds on to a wire, but is angled in such that I can't compress the tabs, nor was I able to reinsert clip.

In the highly likely event that I can't complete this repair, are below reasonable steps to take? Are there any other considerations one should have?  Would typical gas station mechanics be interested/capable of potential wiring problems? Do I need to find a repair center specializing electrical services?

```
Request a tow/carrier for front wheel drive car to repair place.
Attempt to secure loose alternator, electrical wires.
Leave alternator belts, radiator fans, nuts, clips, trim in back of car.
Request shop complete alternator repair/replacement.
Request shop to diagnose, and fix electrical problem.
```

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Why not describe exactly what's going on ... lots of smart people here who could most likely help you.

Comment: Thanks, made a new question. So frustrating to get the alternator nearly out, but a stubborn clip prevents me from fully removing it. Turned out way more difficult than a break pad replacement :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that sounds like a good plan.

I used to get many "Monday Morning" jobs to sort out for customers who had tried fitting lights, radios etc etc

Most places will have slots "spare" for exactly this type of customer issue.

MOST important: make sure you tell them EVERYTHING you did and did not do... ie forgetting to mention that you drained the oil is catastrophic...

Comment: Got some mechanic references. One didnt want to due to concerns about picking up my botched job. But what a difference a professional makes, resolved in two hours. One thing one should keep organized is to keep bolts with the parts you take off, so that another person does not need to retrace your steps. (i organized bolts by order, i took off), but a professional wont know your exact steps.